# Cascading select/dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, select, ng-options

This is duplicate question, but I could'n get my cascading dropdown working after reading couple of good answers. Both dropdown are working, but when I try to filter the second one, I can't make it.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
         <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedReason" ng-options="reason.returnreasonId as reason.returnText for reason in returnreasons">
         </select>
         <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDefectdesc" ng-options="defectdesc.defectdescId as defectdesc.text for defectdesc in defectDescs  | filter:{returnreasonReturnreasonId.returnreasonId: selectedReason.returnreasonId }">
         </select>

</div>
```

**returnReason JSON**

```
<returnreasons>
    <returnreason>
    <languageLanguageId>
     <languageId>1</languageId>
       <lastUpdate>2015-05-19T16:51:11+03:00</lastUpdate>
       <name>svenska</name>
     </languageLanguageId>
     <returnText>Product is broken</returnText>
     <returnreasonId>1</returnreasonId>
   </returnreason>
   <returnreason>
     <languageLanguageId>
       <languageId>2</languageId>
       <lastUpdate>2015-05-19T16:51:11+03:00</lastUpdate>
       <name>english</name>
     </languageLanguageId>
    <returnText>VISUAL FAULT IN THE PRODUCT</returnText>
    <returnreasonId>2</returnreasonId>
  </returnreason>
  <returnreason>
     <languageLanguageId>
       <languageId>3</languageId>
       <lastUpdate>2015-05-19T16:51:11+03:00</lastUpdate>
       <name>suomi</name>
     </languageLanguageId>
  <returnText>HUOLLON TARVE TAI LISÄTYÖ</returnText>
  <returnreasonId>3</returnreasonId>
  </returnreason>
</returnreasons>
```

**defectDesc json**

```
<defectdescs>
  <defectdesc>
    <brandtype>0</brandtype>
    <defectdescId>1</defectdescId>
    <languageLanguageId>...</languageLanguageId>
      <lastUpdated>2015-07-01T16:04:19+03:00</lastUpdated>
  <returnreasonReturnreasonId>
    <languageLanguageId>...</languageLanguageId>
    <returnText>VISUAL FAULT IN THE PRODUCT</returnText>
    <returnreasonId>2</returnreasonId>
  </returnreasonReturnreasonId>
  <text>painting</text>
</defectdesc>
<defectdesc>
  <brandtype>0</brandtype>
  <defectdescId>2</defectdescId>
  <languageLanguageId>
    <languageId>1</languageId>
    <lastUpdate>2015-05-19T16:51:11+03:00</lastUpdate>
   <name>svenska</name>
  </languageLanguageId>
  <lastUpdated>2015-07-01T16:11:17+03:00</lastUpdated>
  <returnreasonReturnreasonId>
    <languageLanguageId>
      <languageId>1</languageId>
      <lastUpdate>2015-05-19T16:51:11+03:00</lastUpdate>
      <name>suomi</name>
    </languageLanguageId>
  <returnText>HUOLLON TARVE TAI LISÄTYÖ</returnText>
  <returnreasonId>3</returnreasonId>
  </returnreasonReturnreasonId>
  <text>something something</text>
</defectdesc>
...
```

**controller**

```
//Fetching reasons
$scope.returnreasons = returnReasonSvc.query();

//Fetching all defect descriptions
$scope.defectDescs = defectDescSvc.query();
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your codes?

Comment: I am in another computer at the moment, but later. What would you like to know more? returnreasons and defectDescs are in scope and dropdowns are working without filttering. There is nothing else in controller in connection with dropdowns.

Comment: I wanna see your controller.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. I am open to any solution, watch etc. It doesn't need to be filter-version. I just would like to get this working :)